# Format string confusion in fscanf function in C

Tags: c, format-string

*I'm unable to understand below this line , could somebody tell me what it does ?*

```
fscanf(file_pointer, "%*[^\n]");
```

Comment: Try a [`scanf() manual`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf). It matches any character *except* newline, while the `*` suppresses the assignment of the conversion, so the characters are just "*skipped*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) one might see, that:

`*` - assignment-suppressing character which is used not to assign the value being read to any receiveing argument of `fscanf`.

`[^\n]` - conversion specifier which matches any symbol except (`^`) new line (`\n`).

As a result, this `fscanf` reads all symbols until new line is met.

Comment: "*reads a symbol if it is not a new line or, if it is a new line, ignores it.*" -- uhm, it reads *everything up to a newline* and ignores everything that was read.

Comment: @FelixPalmen exactly, fixed now.